# Element centering in Bootstrap 4 and flex

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am beginner webdeveloper.

I have this html:

```
<section class="boxes">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 box1">

            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
               <div class="boxes-caption-text d-inline-block">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque
               </div>

               <div class="boxes-caption-number d-inline-block text-right">
                  <div class="border-top w-25 d-inline-block pt-2">01</div>
               </div>
            </div>

            <div class="boxes-title text-center pt-6">Szkolenia</div>
            <div class="boxes-arrow"></div>

         </div>

         <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 box2 d-flex h-100">
            xx2
         </div>
         <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 box3">
            xx3
         </div>

      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

And css:

```
.boxes {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.boxes .box1 {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("/img/slide1.jpg");
  color: white;
  height: 872px;
}

.boxes .box2 {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("/img/slide2.jpg");
  color: white;
  height: 872px;
}

.boxes .box3 {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("/img/slide3.jpg");
  color: white;
  height: 872px;
}

.boxes-caption-text {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 50px 0 0 50px;
  width: 40%;
}

.boxes-caption-number {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 50px 50px 0 0;
}

.boxes-title {
  font-size: 35px;
  vertical-align: 50%;
}

.boxes-arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  width: 55px;
  height: 13px;
  background-image: url("/img/white-arrow.png");
}
```

I make my project in Bootstrap 4.

I want make something like this: https://ibb.co/WxHTfbM

My actual preview (I make first box): https://ibb.co/dfB1G07

I have problem with center arrow and set it on bottom and with text "szkolenia" (I need set it on center div).

How can I make it?

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create this rule and place it in your css.

```
.container-fluid .row .col-12.col-lg-4 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: It's work :) Thank you. How can I center my arrow and add padding-bottom: https://ibb.co/12wBz1y / :)

Comment: try adding `align-items: center` to the rule I wrote above.